# Color special values in dataset

Tags: python, colors, points

How can I allocate colors to specific values in a dataset?

For example:
`0 = orange`
`1 = red`
`2 = green`
.....
`7 = blue`.

Thanks, and happy easter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a dictionary:

```
dict = {'0':'orange', '1':'red', .....}
```

and then each time you see 0, 1 ... you can access the right color with

```
dict[X] ##with X = 0 or 1....
```